# String[] Array to another Activity through Intent (Main activity extends fragment class)

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-intent

EDIT Proper context

Ok so that its in the right context..my main activity has a fragment class, when the user gets to the fragment class, there is an OnClick method on the Main activity, which is where i put this code...

this is what I have tried
Activity 1

```
    context = this;
    db = new MyDBEmbrASD(this);
    List<ResourceTable> resources = db.getAllResource();
    String[] imgFPString = new String[resources.size()];
    String[] imgDrawable = new String[resources.size()];
    String[] temprdm = new String[resources.size()];

    //resources = db.getResources(); // you would not typically call this on     the main thread

    System.out.println("TESTESTESTESTESTEST");
    for (int i = 0; i < resources.size(); i++) {
        imgFPString[i] = resources.get(i).getimgFP();
        temprdm[i] = imgFPString[i];
        System.out.println(imgFPString[i]);
        imgDrawable[i] = "drawable-mdpi/" + imgFPString[i];
        System.out.println(imgDrawable[i]);
        temprdm[i] = imgFPString[i];
    }

    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(temprdm);
    Collections.shuffle(wordList);
    String[] myShuffledArray = wordList.toArray(new String[wordList.size()]);
    //int essonNumber = 1;
    System.out.println("testestest" + myShuffledArray[1]);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DragActivityV2.class);
    intent.putExtra("mStringArray", myShuffledArray);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String[] myShuffledArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("mStringArray");
System.out.println("shfld array " + myShuffledArray[1]);
```

And i get an error 
 Process: info.androidhive.tabsswipe, PID: 25068
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.tabsswipe/info.androidhive.tabsswipe.dragview.DragActivityV2}: java.lang.NullPointerException

The Intent code was based on the questions already posted here...but my case it still doesnt work...Please help

EDIT This is the entire log error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: info.androidhive.tabsswipe, PID: 27569
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.tabsswipe/info.androidhive.tabsswipe.dragview.DragActivityV2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.dragview.DragActivityV2.onCreate(DragActivityV2.java:83)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27569 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

EDIT

I noticed that when i removed the System.out.println("shfld array " + myShuffledArray[1]);...How can i test/ see my array?

EDIT Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.tabsswipe"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE">

</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivitytest"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.DragDropActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.DraggableTestingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MultiImagesTouchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.dragview.DragActivityV2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: What line generated the NPE? (The answer should be in the stack trace somewhere.)

Comment: Please edit your post and include the entire stack trace of the exception from logcat.

Comment: I posted the red parts of the error...did that help?...Also myShuffledArray is originally a String[], i've been told to put into a ArrayList and bundle...I have tried but , i am having trouble with this so if that would help please post thanks

Comment: I noticed that when i removed the System.out.println("shfld array " + myShuffledArray[1]);...How can i test/ see my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use bundle mechanism then just do (assuming this is data passing between activity):

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(temprdm);
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("mylist", (ArrayList<String>) wordList );
```

Then in the target activity

```
 ArrayList<String> test = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("mylist");
```

As for the communication between fragments and activity *or* communication between fragments, it  cannot be done straightfoward especially in the case where the fragments' activity is not their parent container (Usually, for activity to fragment we can get the instance of the fragment's parent activity through `getActivity()`). Thus android documentation introduced [*Communicating with Other Fragments*](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), the idea is to construct an interface in the fragment and let activity implements it, once it's done you can do any operations within the methods that get overrided from the interface.

There's actually a kind of dummy approach, *not recommended* but it works(other than using listener interface). To make some properties can be passed from fragment to activity, make a separated class to hold some properties then make them static, `class Holder { public static x,y,z; }` with this approach, (the *x*, *y* and *z* values are the same accross different components, no matter how many *Fragments* / *Activity* you create), with this in mind, for example, in a *Fragment* you modify these values then in any *Activity / Fragments* you created you just need to access the values via `Holder.x`, `Holder.y` or so on...

Comment: I get this result...E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: info.androidhive.tabsswipe, PID: 1364
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: When I used my original code...I noticed that when i removed the System.out.println("shfld array " + myShuffledArray[1]);...How can i test/ see my array?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't register this `DragActivityV2` in the manifest yet? Not only your MainAcitivity needs to be registered in the manifest but also this `DragActivityV2`. Register it with `<activity
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:name=".DragActivityV2" >
        </activity>` within `<application..` tag. Also note that if the `DragAcitivityV2` extends some fragments class, you can do this instead : `ArrayList<String>test = getActivity().getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("mylist");`

Comment: Actually Activity 1 IS a fragment class...is that why its not working?...

Comment: the .getActivity is red, what should i put there? sorry i am just a newbie learning thanks

Comment: This is why when you ask some questions you need to give some more details. I didn't even know that your *Activity1* is actually a fragment.  Passing data from fragment to activity cannot be done straightforward, you need listener mechanism for that. Passing from activity to fragment is easy but not vice-versa.

Comment: do i put that code on the fragment class itself or the onclick of the main? does it make a difference?

Comment: @MarkLigot, There's actually a kind of dummy approach (other than using listener) to make some properties can be passed from fragment to activity, make a separated class to hold some properties then make them *static*, `class Holder { public static x,y,z; }` with this approach, (the x, y and z values are the same accross different components, no matter how many Fragments/Activitys you create), with this in mind, for example, in Activity you modify these values then in any Fragment you created you just need to access the values via `Holder.x, Holder.y` or so on...

Answer (score 1):

try to use `Bundle` to send data to next activities with `ArrayList`. you can add into ArrayList by `ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();` and add values by `data.add("my value");`

Comment: I have tried doing bundle also like this    Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] myShuffledArray =b.getStringArray("MY_KEY");
    System.out.println("shfld array " + myShuffledArray);

Comment: I think i'm doing the bundle wrong...can u please show me the snippet for that part thanks